# How to partition hard disk after windows 7 installed

Tags: windows-7, windows, system-reserved-partition

I have installed windows 7 andjust i need to do partition of hard disk in three drive.

Please tell me process to partition hard disk without re-formating window.

Comment: Use the built-in partition manager to achieve your task.

Comment: What is Built in partition manager..??  Can you describe this.?

Comment: `Disk Management`.  There are also hundreds of partition tools that exist, pick one, and use that

Answer (score 1):

In windows 7, follow these steps.  Click the start orb and type "Computer Management" into the search box.  Press enter and when the window opens click "Disk Management" in the left pane.  Wait a moment for Windows to load information about the connected drives.  From here, you can manage your hard drives and create/delete partitions and assign letters.  Just right click on the drive you want, then select the the function you want to perform.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Press Windows + R key and type `diskmgmt.msc` then enter
2. Right click on the unallocated space in your hard disk
3. Then click on new simple volume
4. In the simple volume wizard, click next
5. Accept the default size of new volume or set as per your desire then click next
6. Review your choices and then finish